# jQuery - loop to detect if an element is in a page and reacts accordingly?

Tags: jquery

I am working on a page that has a dynamic list of products - when a buy button is clicked it triggers a script that delivers an iframe with a 3rd party payment system.

The page is running within a CMS so I have limited control over the current functionality and cannot add anything to the 3rd party frame.

I would like to add a loading animation that plays when a buy btn is clicked (with a class of .buyBtn) and triggers the loading anim - which is easy enough - my issue is that i need some loop or someway to detect when the iframe has loaded in the page so I can hide the loading graphic..

Any ideas?  I thought a script containg a loop could be called when the loading gig is enabled which constantly searches for an iframe in the page would solve this - but have no idea how to code this!?

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the third-party script inserts the IFRAME asynchronously (which is what it sounds like from your description): You could use the [jquery.doWhen](https://github.com/epickerel/dowhen) plugin (which abstracts the type of loop you've described) and apply an onload listener to the iframe.  Something like:

```
jQuery.doWhen(function(){
  return !!$('#iframe_id').length
}, function(){
  $('#iframe_id').load(function() { /* do this when frame loaded */ } );
}, { interval: 50 });
```

It might take some playing with the `interval` to find an acceptable value where you'd be very unlikely to encounter the race condition of the iframe being added and its contents loading before you could add the onload listener, but also not polling the DOM excessively.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's load function has a callback doesn't it?  Try something like this:

```
  $('#loadingGif').show();
$('#iframe').load(URL, function(){
  $('#loadingGif').hide();
});
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/uZ5XS/).  You should notice the LOADING GIF text for a split second after clicking on the load button.